# How can I use IfSubStr in a loop or an optional argument?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xstring

I'm trying to define a command for use in a tikz picture that changes its appearance based on characters in an option string.

Here's a simple example.  I want either 8 or 15 lines drawn, depending on whether the option "x" is specified, and I want to change the color of the lines depending on whether the option "b" is specified.

Here's my code (it doesn't compile)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\task[1]{
    \foreach \i in {\IfSubStr{#1}{x}{0}{-7},...,7}{
        \draw[\IfSubStr{#1}{b}{color=blue!20}] (0,0.2 * \i) -- (0.2,0.2 * \i);
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\task{xb}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Can anybody help me achieve my goal?

Comment: You can't this way in the `\foreach` header, most likely, since `\IfSubStr` is unexpandable

Comment: The 2nd `\IfSubStr` is incomplete, by the way

Answer (score 3):

Just one way to make it (a) more flexible and (b) work:

[image: color bars]

I've used a key-value approach for this. You can easily adapt your default preference and even pass own values to your keys.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mytask }
    {
        start  .int_set:N = \l_mytask_start_int,
        start  .default:n = -7,
        start  .initial:n = 0,
        color  .tl_set:N  = \l_mytask_color_tl,
        color  .default:n = {blue!20},
        color  .initial:n = black
    }
\NewDocumentCommand { \task } { O{} }
    {
      \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { mytask } { #1 }
    \foreach \i in {\l_mytask_start_int,...,7}{
        \draw[color=\l_mytask_color_tl] (0,0.2 * \i) -- (0.2,0.2 * \i);
    }
    \group_end:
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\task[start=-2]
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\task[color=green]
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\task[start,color]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

Thanks to @egreg a more expl3-ish version (I don't replace my former code, because using the foreach is still fine):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mytask }
    {
        start  .int_set:N = \l_mytask_start_int,
        start  .default:n = -7,
        start  .initial:n = 0,
        color  .tl_set:N  = \l_mytask_color_tl,
        color  .default:n = {blue!20},
        color  .initial:n = black
    }
\NewDocumentCommand { \task } { O{} }
    {
      \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { mytask } { #1 }
      \int_step_inline:nnnn { \l_mytask_start_int } { 1 } { 7 }
            {
        \draw[color=\l_mytask_color_tl] (0,0.2 * ##1) -- (0.2,0.2 * ##1);
            }
    \group_end:
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\task[start=-2]
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\task[color=green]
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\task[start,color]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I came up with something else that doesn't use `expl3`, which I had never heard of until I read your answer.  I'll have to study this new syntax more before I can intelligently comment further.

Comment: And then you don't need `\foreach`: `\int_step_inline:nnnn { \l_mytask_start_int}{1}{7}{\draw[color=\l_mytask_color_tl] (0,0.2 * ##1) -- (0.2,0.2 * ##1);}`

Answer (score 1):

I was playing with this some more, and I've figured out that even though I can't use `\IfSubStr` in an `\edef`, I can use `\edef` in an `\IfSubStr`.

So I've now got this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\task[1]{
    \IfSubStr{#1}{x}{\edef\starti{0}}{\edef\starti{-7}}
    \IfSubStr{#1}{b}{\edef\drawcolor{blue!20}}{\edef\drawcolor{}}

    \foreach \i in {\starti,...,7}{
        \draw[\drawcolor] (0,0.2 * \i) -- (0.2,0.2 * \i);
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\task{xb}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Not sure why I can't put `color=blue!20` in that second `\edef` (instead of just `blue!20`), but it works the way it is.